# Best way to load a jpeg from an install-time asset pack and show it on a WebView

Tags: android, webview, inputstream, assets

What is the best way to load a jpeg from an install-time asset pack and show it on a WebView?

I got it working in case the jpeg is a regular asset, however, I couldn't get it working optimally with install-time assets:

```
        WebView webView = this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        String sHtmlTemplate = "<img src='file:///android_asset/files/"+file+".jpg' width='100%'/>";
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/files/", sHtmlTemplate, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

UPDATE:
The solution below works, but it is slow. Is there a way to load images directly from InputStream or install-time assets?

```
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            InputStream is = assetManager.open(songNo + ".jpg");

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024000];
            int count;
            while(-1 != (count = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length))) {
                baos.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            baos.flush();
            byte[] imageRaw = baos.toByteArray();
            baos.close();
            is.close();

            String image64 = Base64.encodeToString(imageRaw, Base64.DEFAULT);
            String html = String.format("<img width='100%%25' src='data:image/jpeg;base64,%s' />", image64);
            webView.loadData(html, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with an install time asset? Example please.

Comment: `<img src='file:///android_asset/files/"+file+".jpg'` Isn't `<img src='file+".jpg'` enough? Just relative? For what else that base url?

Comment: @blackapps - I created an install-time asset pack based on the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery/integrate-java#java - however, I have a hard time reading and loading the jpegs from this asset pack.

Comment: I will not read that all. Please explain where the new jpg's should land if you install an assets pack. There is nothing in your code that has anything to do with it!?

Comment: @blackapps - yes, you are right, that code is garbage, it is not working with install-time assets. As the documentation says, it should be loaded to an InputStream first, and this should be loaded (somehow) to the WebView.

Comment: Well try to post some code. Then we will see. (And i did not say it was garbage as i read nothing..)

Comment: I see you posted your code. I see nothing that has anything to do with  assets pack. You just try to get a file from normal assets resource. You did not tell it but i asked what installing such a pack would do and you did not tell that files would be added to assets resource. But anyhow its logic. What i'm missing is if you can load new html files that were added using an assets pack?

Comment: `InputStream is = assetManager.open(songNo + ".jpg");` That does not match your `files` dir in 'file:///android_asset/files/".

Comment: `webView.loadData(baos.toString()` No. No. You can never load a jpg using the String class. Its no text. No string. And why would it be base64? Hmmm. You can use the string class for a bas64 encoded string of course.. But a .jpg is not such encoded.

Comment: `.. but the image still not showing.` But can you load from assets and assign to an ImageView?

Comment: Try to list() the files in your assets resource. It will show you how files from pack are added.

Comment: `InputStream is = assetManager.open(songNo + ".jpg");` You will get an IOException if the file is not there. Where are you handling it?

Comment: Yes, the file is there, the binary jpg is loading into the internal variables, but it is not showing on the webview.

Comment: Not with that code of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the WebView is not the most optimal way to show a jpg in this case. I ended up using another control:

```
        com.ortiz.touchview.TouchImageView touchView = this.findViewById(R.id.touchImageView);
        try {
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            InputStream is = assetManager.open(songNo + ".jpg");
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is,"src");
            touchView.setImageDrawable(d);

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.i("xxx", e.getMessage());
        }
```